How to watch DRM-protected content on a second screen in Edge? (Multiple monitors or VGA cable error)
When trying to watch content from the UK's Channel 4 on a display other than the primary monitor using Microsoft Edge, the following error is displayed:

Their MS Edge FAQ says:

Why can't I watch content on the Microsoft Edge browser with a second monitor?
The Microsoft Edge browser returns a DRM error when you try to watch protected content and are using certain monitors or cables, such as VGA. This is because the media extension within Edge views the connection as unsafe, meaning protected content could be decrypted. There are two ways to continue watching content on Channel 4 while using one of these connections:
Change to another one of our supported HTML5 browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari)
Or you can use a different connection, such as HDMI, to view content on another monitor.

Edge plays the video fine if you have no other monitor connected. I am using a HDMI cable, not a VGA cable - via a laptop dock/port replicator.
How can we workaround this without having to switch browsers?


Open up the URL edge://flags
Search for DRM
Disable PlayReady DRM for Windows
Enable Widevine DRM
Restart Edge
Grab some popcorn!

